# Reading data into a data frame

Tags: r, types, dataframe

I am trying to read data from a CSV file into a data frame. The data contains names which I do not want to have as factors. I cannot use the `stringAsFactors=FALSE` argument since there are other columns which I want to have as factors.

How do I achieve the desired behavior?

Note : The data has thousands of columns...I need to modify the datatype only for one column..the types assigned by default for the rest are all fine

Comment: Use the argument `colClasses` to specify the data type for each column. Check `? read.csv` for documentation on `colClasses`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `colClasses` argument to specify the type of each column.  For example:

```
x <- read.csv("myfile.csv", colClasses=c("numeric","factor","character"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could specify the column classes. From  `?read.table`

```
colClasses: character.  A vector of classes to be assumed for the
      columns.  Recycled as necessary, or if the character vector
      is named, unspecified values are taken to be 'NA'.

      Possible values are 'NA' (the default, when 'type.convert' is
      used), '"NULL"' (when the column is skipped), one of the
      atomic vector classes (logical, integer, numeric, complex,
      character, raw), or '"factor"', '"Date"' or '"POSIXct"'.
      Otherwise there needs to be an 'as' method (from package
      'methods') for conversion from '"character"' to the specified
      formal class.

      Note that 'colClasses' is specified per column (not per
      variable) and so includes the column of row names (if any).
```

So something like:

```
types = c("numeric", "character", "factor")
read.table("file.txt", colClasses = types)
```

should do the trick.

**Personally**, I would just read the columns in as strings *or* factors and then change the columns you want.

Comment: +1 for the two-step approach. This is what I use most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14524412/697568) states, if you know the name of the column before reading in your data, you can use a named character vector to specify that column only.

```
types <- c(b="character") #Set the column named "b" to character
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,sep=",",colClasses=types,text="
a,b,c,d,e
1,asdf,morning,4,greeting
5,fiewhn,evening,12,greeting
9,ddddd,afternoon,292,farewell
33,eianzpod,evening,1111,farewell
191,dnmxzcv,afternoon,394,greeting
")
sapply(df,class)
#          a           b           c           d           e 
#  "integer" "character"    "factor"   "integer"    "factor"
```

If there is no header, you can also do it by position:

```
types <- c(V2="character") #Set the second column to character
df <- read.table(header=FALSE,sep=",",colClasses=types,text="
1,asdf,morning,4,greeting
5,fiewhn,evening,12,greeting
9,ddddd,afternoon,292,farewell
33,eianzpod,evening,1111,farewell
191,dnmxzcv,afternoon,394,greeting
")
sapply(df,class)
#       V1          V2          V3          V4          V5 
#"integer" "character"    "factor"   "integer"    "factor"
```

And finally, if you know the position but have a header, you can build the vector of appropriate length. For `colClasses`, `NA` means default.

```
types <- rep.int(NA_character_,5) #make this length the number of columns
types[2] <- "character" #force the second column as character
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,sep=",",colClasses=types,text="
a,b,c,d,e
1,asdf,morning,4,greeting
5,fiewhn,evening,12,greeting
9,ddddd,afternoon,292,farewell
33,eianzpod,evening,1111,farewell
191,dnmxzcv,afternoon,394,greeting
")
sapply(df,class)
#       V1          V2          V3          V4          V5 
#"integer" "character"    "factor"   "integer"    "factor"
```